# How can I find position of matched regex of a single string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, special-variables

Let's say `my $string = "XXXXXTPXXXXTPXXXXTP";`
If I want to match: `$string =~ /TP/;` multiple times and return the position for each, how would I do so?

I have tried`$-[0]`, `$-[1]`, `$-[2]` but I only get a position for `$-[0]`.

EDIT:
I have also tried the global modifier `//g` and it still does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$-[1]` is the position of the text captured by the first capture. Your pattern has no captures.

By calling `//g` in scalar context, only the next match is found, allowing you to grab the position of that match. Simply do this until you've found all the matches.

```
while ($string =~ /TP/g) {
   say $-[0];
}
```

Of course, you could just as easily store them in a variable.

```
my @positions;
while ($string =~ /TP/g) {
   push @positions, $-[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is useful as I will need to store them in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "XXXXXTPXXXXTPXXXXTP";

# Set position to 0 in order for \G anchor to work correctly
pos ($str) = 0;

while ( $str =~ /\G.*?TP/s) {
    say ($+[0] - 2);
    pos ($str) = $+[0]; # update position to end of last match
}
```

Comment: Ah, this works! does this have something to do with greedy?

Comment: @Matt Yes the operator `.*?` is non-greedy. It is essential.

Comment: @ikegami yes, of course.. thanks.. at least it still works :) But using regex without `\g`, I need to set `pos` of course..

Comment: Wow... That's way too complicated. You've basically reimplemented `/g`.